# Dont allow the user to login multiple times

Tags: java

I am trying to stop multiple Logging in to my application , for which i am using this approach :

First time user logs in i saved the user in a session , Second time user tries to login again , I first check with the session , if the session already have the same user in it ,I Dont allow the user to sign in Again .

This approach works Well in Same browser , But if i try to login Again with same user From Another browser , It allows multiple login because there is nothing in the session then.

Same issue happens if i try to login from some other computer .

Please suggest .
Thanks

Here is what i have

```
           User user = (User) rdbHelper.getAuthentication(userid, password);
    if(user!=null)
    {
        session=getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);
        User loggedInUser = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

        if(user.getId() == loggedInUser.getId()){
        user.setId(0); // making user null and stopping user to login
        }else{
        session=getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("user", user); // allow user to sing in
        }
```

Comment: This cannot be done using just a session, but you need to store IP address in database and based on that you need to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you can try to achieve that:

- As soon as user logs in Store his IP address, his name and /or some random generated token in some table in the database.
- When user logs out, clear those previously stored values from the table.
- During login process, check that table to see if user information is already there in the table, if information is available, then it indicates user has logged in from some other computer, browser etc and deny login access.
- If information is not available, then allow user to login.

But of-course this is not a fool proof, depending on your needs you may need to add adiitional columns etc.

Also there are some cons in this approach which needs to be handled, one of the case is:

1) What happens if user's PC shut's down or user doesn't bother to log out? In that case user will be denayed access.

In this case, there should be some job running at specific interval of time to do clean up process. You may need to add "Timestamp" column to your lookup table, the main work of that job is it will compare timestamp with some pre-defined timeout value (say 10mins) and delete all those rows.

So again user can login without problem.

Comment: thanks , but what if the user computer just shut down accidently  and user didnt logg out himself, with this approach , i think he will never be able to login again

Comment: @junaidp, I have edited :) In that case, there should be some job running at specific interval of time to clean up the table, just like session time out.

Comment: thanks :) . This approach is good , But do you mean that all the time there will be a call to the db after every 10 min ..Even if the user pc is working fine and he is working on my application .. In that case this job running at specif time interval will go to the db after 10 min and remove everything Even if the user is using the application smoothly(NO PC HANGUP OR ANYTHING).. but the db table is now clear , SO... an other user can then login .. Am i right ?

Comment: @junaidp, this job will run different process than application. Also you need to have another flag to know whether user is still running on app or not. :)

Comment: correct , thanks , Umm If you could give an idea how we check if the user is still running on app..

Comment: Keep on updating timestamp column at regular intervals while user is doing operations, if there is no timestamp at fixed session timeout, then it's assume user is idle and clear the data and log him out :)

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in through a web browser you make the session like normal, then on a database you state that they are logged in. when they try to log in again you check the database for the user and if they are logged in dont allow them to on the new page.

When they log out you destroy the session but you would also need to set the database to say that they are not logged in. this will stop people logging in from different browsers

Comment: thanks , but what if the user computer just shut down accidently OR user close the browser with out logging out himself, with this approach , i think he will never be able to login again

Comment: You add a session variable for time. This is how i do it. if they have the time variable set when they visit the page then check the time and compare to time now if its over x minutes then remove the session variable for username which will allow them to log back in

Comment: but that thing should only be checking IF there is inactivity for x Minutes , otherwise it will clear the session/db (Even if user is still working on my application).. And the other user will be able to signIn, So multiple login issue will arise again

Comment: session_start();
 
 if(isset($_SESSION['time_stamp']) && (time() - $_SESSION['time_stamp'] > 1800))
 {
  unset($_SESSION['valid_user']);
  unset($_SESSION['time_stamp']);
  session_destroy();
 }
    if(isset($_SESSION['time_stamp']) && (time() - $_SESSION['time_stamp'] < 1800))
    {
        $_SESSION['time_stamp'] = time();
    }
 if(isset($_POST['login']))
 {
           //login code here
        }


This piece of code i use refreshes the session variable if they are still logged in, so if they use your site then everytime they change page it updates the time variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can take one extra field in users table with the column name "IsLoggedIn" as bit field and set it to true until the user is logged out. As soon as user logs out set it to false. This need to be done for session expiry time also. As soon as the session expires this field should be set to false automatically using triggers or thru SP call. 
While trying to log in from different browsers or computers, it should check the "IsLoggedIn" field if it's already true, and if it's not, let the user login.

Comment: thanks , can you give an idea how can i call the db when the session timed out , How will i know in the code that session is timed out.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation in the project we work on, and the approach we took was:

1. Generate a token whenever user logs in and store it in the session and database for this user.
2. Upon each request to the server, verify the token, to make sure that he is in a valid    session and he did not come back after a time out. (Any request with a time gap of more than    15 minutes and we invalidate the token)
3. If the user tries to login again (for example from a different browser or without logging off), we can see that the token still exists in the database for this user and we show a warning message to the user if he wants to "kill" the old session. This way, even if the computer crashes or he forgets to logout, he can decide to kill the old session and continue with the new session. Or he can cancel creation of the new token to still be working on old session.
4. Ofcourse, if the user clicks on "logout", we clear the token

Comment: can you me with your this statement , How you do that :  even if the computer crashes or he forgets to logout, he can decide to kill the old session and continue with the new session

Answer (score 0):

Try storing data in the servlet context.  When a user logs in

```
context = getServletContext();
List<string> logins = context.getAttribute("logins");
logins.add(username);
```

A check for login could work something like this.

```
context = getServletContext();
List<string> logins = context.getAttribute("logins");
if (!logins.contains(username)) {
   login();
} else {
   deny();
}
```

Use a servletContextListener to create the list on application start.

I would use a HttpSessionListener to manage the list.  When a session ends, check if it was logged in and remove the login name from the list.